# Modify distance of enumerate item in tcolorbox

Tags: enumerate, tcolorbox

i want to add line (A) and change distance between rows (B)

My code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=10cm]

\begin{enumerate}
\item
...........:...........     ..............................................\\
........................  \hfill XXX
%\vspace*{1.5cm}
\item
...........:...........     ..............................................\\
........................  \hfill XXX
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enumitem` package allows the simple specification of various list parameters, including (in this case) `itemsep` to set the vertical gap between items.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,enumitem}
\newcommand\linegap[1]{\underline{\hspace{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=10cm]

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=1.5cm,leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=.5in]
\item
\linegap{35pt}:\linegap{35pt}     \linegap{135pt}\\
\linegap{75pt}  \hfill A
\item
...........:...........     ..............................................\\
........................  \hfill A
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I can think of various interpretations for what the OP means by the "B" issue.  Here is a possibility.  In addition to using `itemsep`, the `setspace` package is employed to temporarily set the line spacing:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,enumitem,setspace}
\newcommand\linegap[1]{\underline{\hspace{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=10cm]
\begin{spacing}{2.5}
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=1.5cm,leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=.5in]
\item
\linegap{35pt}:\linegap{35pt}     \linegap{135pt}\\
\linegap{75pt}  \hfill A
\item
...........:...........     ..............................................\\
........................  \hfill A
\end{enumerate}
\end{spacing}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: B.Segietes. Thank for your fast reply. Sorry, I uploading image slow and can you help to change A & B in my uploaded image.

Comment: @latexforti I have taken care of the "A" issue but with regard to vertical distance "B", is it between the 1st line and what follows? is it between every line?  or is it between items?

Comment: (B-green) is between every line. I don't want to use (\\\) and tried added \vspace*{0.3cm}  but not but not effort. Thanks

Comment: @latexforti Please see my edit.  I use the `spacing` environment to set temporarily the line spacing.